# Seaborn PointPlot Category Ordering Issue

Tags: python, seaborn

I have been trying to use pointplot in Seaborn and in general it does what I need and I'm very impressed with the functionality.

My use case is fairly standard:

```
sns.pointplot(x="Category_1", y="Parameter", hue="Category 2", data=df);
```

My issue is that the Category I use for the hue contains strings in the form:

```
"1 string1", "2 string2", "3 string3", etc....
```

This is by design so that I can get a particular order if I sort. However when I run the Seaborn function the order is different.

By what logic does Seaborn order this, and is there a way for forcing a desired order. If I do:

```
A = df.Category2.unique()
A.sort()
```

I get the list order that I want.

Ben

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in the [tutorial](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html), categorical plotting functions follow a set of rules to determine the order of plot elements:

- If a sequence of categories is passed to the `order` parameter, that order is used.
- If the variable is a pandas `Categorical` with an assigned category order, that order is used.
- If the variable is numeric, the values are shown in sorted order
- Otherwise, the values are shown in the order that they appear in the DataFrame.